# Some Control of wpf does not work properly in all computer from server

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

i have created a WPF application and put it on server(Server 2012 R2) and try to run it from different computer which are connected through LAN. i am running this application by accessing server from different computer and its work fine in all computer but not in one computer. the actual problem is when i click submit button from that computer my computer screen get white and could not respond me anything and also not given any error. The work of that button is to generate invoice(in crystal report) and also save that invoice report as PDF.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think on submit button you have some database query and in your case the connection to database may not be proper or error in connection so check your connection of database and check connectionstring.

Comment: Thanks for replay but its work fine with other computers and all shared server's database so if there is problem with database connection then application show error on every computer when i press that button.

Comment: ok you have problems only in some computers of your network right?

Comment: Yes, actually right now i have problem with only one computer.

Comment: hahaha then check that computer configuration..... i cant do anything without get physical connection to that computer..

Comment: you're Welcome... and if your problem get solved then accept my answer as a solution by ticking green sign at the answer.....